# How to make HTML code inactive with comments

Tags: html, xhtml

I have some HTML code on a page that I don't want to erase, but make inactive for the short term. How can I make the browser ignore parts of the page in the same way the `//` works in some programming languages?

Comment: can you explain more briefly??

Comment: chk this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_comment.asp

Comment: `<!-- This is a comment for html page and it will not display in the browser -->`

Comment: <!-- Every-thing inisibile in the browser --> more details http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_comments.htm

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Behold HTML comments:

```
<!-- comment -->
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/intro/sgmltut.html#idx-HTML

The proper way to delete code without deleting it, of course, is to use version control, which enables you to resurrect old code from the past. Don't get into the habit of accumulating commented-out code in your pages, it's no fun. :)

Comment: Thank You deceze. That was it.

Comment: The times, when version control was still not seen as an absolute, obvious must.

Answer (score 14):

**HTML Comments:**

```
<!-- <div> This div will not show </div> -->
```

[See Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_Importance_of_Correct_Commenting)

**CSS Comments:**

```
/* This style will not apply */
```

[See Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Comments)

**JavaScript Comments:**

```
// This single line JavaScript code will not execute
```

**OR**

```
/*
   The whole block of JavaScript code will not execute
*/
```

[See Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Code_comments)

Comment: I saw the CSS comments thinking they were for HTML and they did not work... Thanks :).

Answer (score 4):

To comment block with nested comments: substitute inner (block) comments from "--" to "++"

```
<!-- *********************************************************************
     * IMPORTANT: To uncomment section
     *            sub inner comments "++" -> "--" & remove this comment
     *********************************************************************
<head>
   <title>My document's title</title> <++! My document's title ++>
   <link rel=stylesheet href="mydoc.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<++! My document's important HTML stuff ++>
...
...
...
</body>

*********************************************************************
* IMPORTANT: To uncomment section
*            sub inner comments "++" -> "--" & remove this comment
*********************************************************************
-->
```

Thus, the outer most comment ignores all "invalid" inner (block) comments.

Comment: i didn't know about <!++ ++>, Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Just create a multi-line comment around it. When you want it back, just erase the comment tags.

For example, `<!-- Stuff to comment out or make inactive -->`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<!-- This is a comment for an HTML page and it will not display in the browser -->
```

For more information, I think *[3 On SGML and HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html)* may help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) then the keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> to add a group of code. To make a comment line or select the code, right click -> *Source* -> *Add Block Comment*.

To remove the block comment, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> or right click -> *Source* -> *Remove Block comment*.

Comment: Can you add an example of the content before and after these operations?

Comment: ya sure @PeterMortensen                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                     <p>hello</p>
after pressing Ctrl+Shift+/  the code will turns into
                    <!-- <p>hello</p> -->
while pressing Ctrl+Shift+\  the code will turns into 
                    <p>hello</p>

Answer (score -1):

Reason of comments:

1. Comment out elements temporarily rather than removing them, especially if they've been left unfinished.
2. Write notes or reminders to yourself inside your actual HTML documents.
3. Create notes for other scripting languages like JavaScript which requires them

**HTML Comments**

```
<!-- Everything is invisible  -->
```