# Can I hide my websites footer without erasing code?

Tags: html, css

I dont want my websites footer for a short while.
Is there any way to hide this without erasing the code?

```
#footer wrap{
}
```

Comment: You can simply comment it out in your html `<!--` your code `-->`

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393699/how-to-make-html-code-inactive-with-comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should try...

```
#footer wrap{
visibility : hidden;
}
```

...it will definitely hide your footer.

Answer (score 3):

```
#footer wrap{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
#footer_wrap {
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either hide it with CSS by setting the `display` attribute to `none`

```
#footer wrap{
    display: none;
}
```

or commenting the tag out in your HTML with `<--` and `-->`