# HTML -- the line after a comment

Tags: html, css

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        <!-- comment -->
        h2 {color:#34DE56;}
        p  {text-indent:25px;}
    </style>
</head>
```

---

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        h2 {color:#34DE56;}
        p  {text-indent:25px;}
    </style>
</head>
```

Hey everyone I know this may be the most basic question about html but I couldn't find the reason behind it.

Upper code contains a comment. When I put this comment before any line, the following line does not get read. The rest works alright.

Basically the colouring part does not work when I put a comment in the previous line. When I delete the comment it works just the way it's supposed to.

Comment: you forgot to close the <style> tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make HTML code inactive with comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393699/how-to-make-html-code-inactive-with-comments)

Comment: @Supersharp I was just copy pasting that was a minor mistake sorry..

Comment: You should use the CSS syntax for comments (see answer below)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For css use:

```
/* Comment */
```

For html use:

```
<!-- Comment -->
```

Comment: or for one line comments in css ```// comment```

Comment: @weilder i'm not sure

Comment: @weidler that works in **SCSS** / **SASS** but not in pure **CSS**

Comment: whups yeah, well then... just ignore me :D

Answer (score 0):

That is invalid comment syntax for css, thats valid for html not for css

```
/* valid css comments */
```

And

```
<!-- valid html comments -->
```

For more details:

- [Css Comments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Comments)